# Reactivity issue in VueJs - unnecessary updates

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a Vue application, which renders a nested tree-like data structure. The structure has only two cases - boolean values at the leaves of the tree and key-value records as internal tree nodes.

The boolean case is internally encoded as `{ type: 'bool', value: <boolean value> }` record.
The record case is internally encoded as `{ type: 'record', value: <js object> }`.
The 'type' field makes it easier to dispatch between Vue components to render a particular case:

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue2-reactivity-issue-kbg4c

The boolean case component allows to switch the value of the boolean by clicking on it.

Now suppose the following structure is rendered:

```
record({
  a: record({ a1: bool, a2: bool }),
  b: bool,
  c: bool,
  d: record({ d1: bool, d2: bool })
});
```

When I click on the bool corresponding to the "a1" field, I see that "a1" and "a2" components are being updated. *I've inserted trace to the "updated" component hook, so it's visible in the console what components are updated.*

When I click on the bool corresponding to the "b" field, *every* components in the application is being updated - even the most nested one like "d1" and "d2".

This seems to me as unnecessary updates.
Why do they happen and how to avoid it?

Comment: I think that you should try using an array instead of object - something like `[{id: number, value: boolean, title: string, children: array}]` Then, using `v-for` and `:key` Vue will be able to patch only those VNodes whose data was changed (using the key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the good point to start is this article https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

The first issue that you link `bool` object over the whole state.

The second one that you modify entirely state every mutation.

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue2-reactivity-issue-ocy0h

Comment: Ah, a good catch of the `bool` object shared across the whole state! With that being fixed the issue boils down to the way the state is updated in the `modifyAtom` function. The recreation of the part of the state from scratch triggers a lot of updates, whereas the component-wise update doesn't: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue2-reactivity-issue-forked-388z3?file=/src/store/index.js

I don't quite understand what's the difference though. Why are the repercussions so severe? `Version 2` makes the *whole* component tree to be updated. I would have expected a more localized impact.